# automatic switching of ruby versions non-interactive shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ubuntu, rvm, sh

### Background

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
RVM version: 1.18.16 (stable)
default ruby: ruby 1.9.3-p385 (via rvm)

### Confirmation RVM is working and the .rvmrc is trusted

```
$ bash -lc 'cd /home/client1/websites/site1; ruby -v' - client1
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-linux]

$ bash -lc 'cd /home/client1/websites/site2; ruby -v' - client1
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02

$ bash -lc 'rvm rvmrc trusted /home/client1/websites/site2/.rvmrc'
The rvmrc at '/home/client1/websites/site2/.rvmrc' is currently trusted.
```

### Desired Effect

```
$ bash -c 'cd /home/client1/websites/site2; ruby -v' - client1
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-linux]

$ bash -c 'cd /home/client1/websites/site2; ruby -v' - client1
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
```

### Current effect

```
$ bash -c 'cd /home/client1/websites/site2; ruby -v' - client1
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-linux]

$ bash -c 'cd /home/client1/websites/site2; ruby -v' - client1
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-linux]
```

### Things tried

placing:
`[[ -s /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && . /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`
within the following files:

- ~/.bashrc,
- ~/.profile,
- ~/.bash_profile,
- /etc/bash.bashrc

all right at the very top of the file, before anything else could cause an issue.

**Side note:** I have tried using the .ruby-version method also which doesn't appear to work either (thanks to mpapis on irc)

Answer (score 1):

In general bash needs to be invoked a certain way to process various profile/rc files. Try executing bash as `bash -L -c "your command here"` instead, which actives login mode for properly parsing all the necessary startup files.

**Edit**: If a login shell is not wanted then interactive mode must be forced to automatically source `~/.bashrc`. This is because `-c` prevents a normal interactive console from being instantiated. This can be done with `bash -i -c "command"`.

Comment: Apologies, the original 3 commands where meant to have -l in to show that login mode is ok.. this is required in a non-login mode environment (if at all possible)

Comment: @DavidC Given that you're using `-c` you other need to use `-i` for forcing interactive mode or `-L` to use login mode if you want files to be sourced automatically as per the edits above. Also login mode is less about requiring login and more about sourcing files that would be sourced if you logged into a terminal.